# File reading in html

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I want to know if there are any methods other than file reading api and `XMLHttprequest()` to read/load text files which support almost all the web browsers.
I'm not using `xmlhttprequest()` since it cannot be run in few browsers, like chrome(since it has a bug) [you may find it here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37586)
I would like to know pure javascript/html methods for this and would like to avoid php and django scripts.

I tried following xmlhttprequest method

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <body>  
    <script>
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && winddow.Blob) { //alert('Great success! All the File APIs are supported.');
}
    else {
  alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'text.txt');
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {
      var lines = req.responseText.split(/\n/g);
      lines.forEach(function(line, i) {
        alert(line);
      });
    } else {
       (alert("please update your browser,this webpage doesnt have     support for your browser"))
    }
  }
}
req.send();
    </script>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

This runs in firefox 35.0.1
But when I try using it in chrome it doesn't work
But if I remove the condition `if(req.status==200)` then I receive one alert which has no text.

Comment: So run chrome to allow file access.

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far.

Comment: Ah the famous http status codes. 200: "OK", not 200: "update your browser"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user-controlled file-api and scriptable XMLHTTPRequest are pretty much the only options. Alternatively, you might have luck with java or flash or silverlight (etc) approaches (I'll leave that up to other answers for now).

Alternatives for your own (development) machine:
For chrome you could allow XMLHttpRequest to access files from other files using:
`--allow-file-access-from-files`
That would be at least safer then using: `--disable-web-security`

Another quick solution would be "tiny": https://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/tinyweb/download.php
I like it because it is *small*!! Then (either via loop-back ip or local machine ip or host-name via hostfile) I work around those limitations, clearing the path for cookie/sandbox/local-storage features and the problem you are trying to solve.

However that doesn't help with a simple distributable html/javascript-app... As you pointed out, it is currently a "won't-fix" for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the text file, you could edit it to be

```
var text = "ORIGINAL TEXT"
```

And add the file as a script tag.